# get_current_user_id in WordPress using Timber returns 0

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm using Timber on a WordPress site. I'm developing a theme and I need to have access to the current user ID.

I'm connected as an admin and I know my user ID : 12.

I tried to call `get_current_user_id` directly in the twig file but it returned 0.

Same thing after trying to call the same function from the `functions.php` file with this thing : `add_action('init', 'my_function')`. Always 0...

I also tried other functions like `wp_get_current_user` for example. Again, it's like I'm not connected.

I think the thing is that I use Timber, but I'm not sure, because I didn't see any problem like this that is related to Timber on the web.

**EDIT :**

Here is my twig template file `template-projects.twig` :

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="projects container">
    <div class="projects__filters" id="project-filters">
        {{ fn('get_current_user_id') }}
    </div>
</div>

...

{% endblock %}
```

I have a `project` variable that is available. What I want to do is to display the user-related project (it's a custom field in the project). For now, I'm just trying to get the ID and display it before adding any code.

This is my php template file, `template-projects.php` :

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Projects
 * Description: Projects
 */

$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['post'] = $post;
$context['searchBar'] = true;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'  => 'project-v3'
);
$context['projects'] = Timber::get_posts($args);

Timber::render('template-projects.twig', $context);
```

I get the post, the projects, everything is fine, I tried to get the user ID from here too, but it doesn't work either.

**EDIT 2 :**

I found the solution !

I'm using `gruntjs` with `BrowserSync`, which creates the the domain `localhost:3000` instead of the hostname I choosed in Mamp.

It appears that if I use the Mamp hostname, the user data is correctly retrieved, but if I go on the BrowserSync url, it's like I'm not connected and the ID is 0 everytime. It's a bit strange and I will not have an auto-reload of my tab but at least I found the problem :)

Comment: Please share your relevant twig file code

Comment: Please show your relevant code .

Comment: this link can help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

Comment: I edited my question.
@milankyada, when I use this function, everything is empty, but ID still displays 0